# Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (Identity) with shape [1, 4] to a Java object with shape [1, 10, 4]

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

Trained TFLite model of faces and tried to implement it on android.

```
final List<Detector.Recognition> results = detector.recognizeImage(croppedBitmap);
```

on this line i got an error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: inference
    Process: org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection, PID: 14805
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (Identity) with shape [1, 4] to a Java object with shape [1, 10, 4].
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.throwIfDstShapeIsIncompatible(Tensor.java:482)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.copyTo(Tensor.java:252)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:183)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:365)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.recognizeImage(TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java:211)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.DetectorActivity$2.run(DetectorActivity.java:184)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

detector inputs are

```
 // Configuration values for the prepackaged SSD model.
  private static final int TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE = 448; // before was 300 and gave error
  private static final boolean TF_OD_API_IS_QUANTIZED = true;
  private static final String TF_OD_API_MODEL_FILE = "model.tflite";
  private static final String TF_OD_API_LABELS_FILE = "labels.txt";
  private static final DetectorMode MODE = DetectorMode.TF_OD_API;
  // Minimum detection confidence to track a detection.
  private static final float MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE_TF_OD_API = 0.5f;
  private static final boolean MAINTAIN_ASPECT = false;
  private static final Size DESIRED_PREVIEW_SIZE = new Size(640, 480);
  private static final boolean SAVE_PREVIEW_BITMAP = false;
  private static final float TEXT_SIZE_DIP = 10;

 int cropSize = TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE;

try {
  detector =
      TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.create(
          this,
          TF_OD_API_MODEL_FILE,
          TF_OD_API_LABELS_FILE,
          TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE,
          TF_OD_API_IS_QUANTIZED);
  cropSize = TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE;
} catch (final IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  LOGGER.e(e, "Exception initializing Detector!");
  Toast toast =
      Toast.makeText(
          getApplicationContext(), "Detector could not be initialized", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
  toast.show();
  finish();
}
```

which parameter should i change it to work? is it problem in java or I should retrain model?

Update:
the problem seems to be in tensorflow library, because of mismatch between input and output map. Hope anyone knows how to eliminate this mismatch. Debug variables are given below.
[error line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbuHu.png)

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jPxu.png)

[output map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFg3K.png)

Update 2:
First I installed demo app from https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview#get_started.
It can detect many objects (person, cat, laptop and so on). Then I trained model
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ezjt7iytvbtSDO2kgnzfLSoVT_lcKzBJ?usp=sharing  following this link https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_image_classification . Maybe I trained it not correct, because on original model tensors shapecopy is [1,10,4] shape and matches copy object shape. when I try to apply my model, shapecopy is [1,4] and it raises exception

[shape mismatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfRvh.png)

Comment: This is model and object where to put answer size mismatch. Look into org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.recognizeImage(TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java:211) under debug and check sizes. To check tflite model output size use Netron or similar.

Comment: @AlexK. please see post update, i debugged and saw input and output map variables content. What should I change then code to work?

Comment: Outputs order looks correct, remain item is model. Do you use standard model like [this](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/lite-model/ssd_mobilenet_v1/1/metadata/1?lite-format=tflite) or any kind of custom trained? Looks like model you are using has 1st output called "Identity" and shape [1][4], while standard object detection models has output shape [1][NUM_DET][4].

Comment: I trained a new model, colab https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ezjt7iytvbtSDO2kgnzfLSoVT_lcKzBJ?usp=sharing

Comment: followed this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_image_classification

Comment: first i used standtard tflite app from https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview#get_started

Comment: @AlexK.yes, output is ok, shapecopy is changing, when i switch models

Answer (score 2):

Used custom model has outputs that differs from used in [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview#get_started)
To update app for changed model:

1. investigate new (custom) model and determine input and output shapes (I prefer to use Netron app for this - open your custom TFLite model with it)
2. change input and output data buffers in application to match corresponding inputs and outputs to your model: example you use matches with your input but output should be changed to (see near TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java@195)

   `resultLabel = new float[1][4];`

   `Map<Integer, Object> outputMap = new HashMap<>();`

   `outputMap.put(0, resultLabel);`

Comment: Hello this is standart model (from demo app) result https://imgur.com/gallery/v2XwIgx], 
and this is https://imgur.com/gallery/2P9CPBJ custom model trained by me.

Comment: Hello, I changed this part of code, error is gone, but now it doesn't detect anything..

Comment: You meant returns the same class all the time?

Comment: No, Recognition results are always empty 

https://imgur.com/gallery/jVGUrvr

Comment: may it be input problem?

Comment: I use input from camera and havent changed much TF demo app

Comment: You are solving image classification task: trying to determine one type of emotion out of four. It will be simpler for you to adapt image classification example than object detection. Take a look at [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/image_classification/overview) it will be familiar to you because you have already seen detection application.

Comment: I wanted to detect face part, that is why I choosed this model...

Comment: You have trained classifier, not a detector. Classifier answers question "What is on picture" like in your case - it classifies yawn, no yawn, eyes open or eyes closed. If you want detector you should have model which outputs detection rectangle, detection class, confidence. And Input data should be annotated with regions of particular class (like eye, mouth, etc.).