# TensorFlowLite tensor shapes make no sense (input: [1, 1, 1, 3])

Tags: java, tensorflow, object-detection, tflite

I trained an object detection model using this [step-by-step tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html) that detects one class: person. It works pretty well too, Finds people of all shapes and sizes and does not mark my easel as person any more. Works great with some normal python tf inference runner I found somewhere.

Now I want to use it on my phone. So I used the default [model converter tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/convert/convert_models) to do that, just to realize that apparently there's something called a "StridedSlice" operator in my model that can't be converted to tflite, so I used the [select tensorflow model operators tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select) to convert it with this one operator included and added the required library to the app, which is basically the default example app coming with detect.tflite:

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:2.8.0'
```

I tried with detect.tflite to make sure this doesn't break anything and it still works like a charm.

The problem is: In tflite's opinion, my model takes a [1, 1, 1, 3] tensor as input now, as confirmed by Netron (which I found thanks to Alex K.'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65081491/4364057)):

[image: Netron analysis]

So it seems that indeed for some reason my model takes a [1, 1, 1, 3] input tensor and provides several output tensors with shapes I don't understand and sadly without any description of what the outputs mean. Also I can't force it do anything, instead it crashes and, as expected by a properly statically typed language:

```
Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (serving_default_input_tensor:0) with 3 bytes from a Java Buffer with 1228800 bytes.
```

because of course my buffer's size is not (1 * 1 * 1 * 3) because that doesn't make any sense. Instead my buffer uses an input size of 640, but not because I'm sure that's the correct size but because I guessed and also my pipeline.config has this.

```
image_resizer {
  fixed_shape_resizer {
    height: 640
    width: 640
  }
}
```

For some reason though, when using the normal python tf inference runner, I can just throw any image in there (same script works on both my laptop's integrated camera and a realsense 3d cam, the laptop one of course has shitty resolution).

So where did I go wrong? The conversion to tflite where it apparently lost information about inputs? Usage in the app where maybe I have to tell it to not listen to the so-called [1, 1, 1, 3] input shape? Somewhere else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing with this issue as I followed the step-by-step tutorial too. After investigating, I managed to change the input to [1,320,320,4].

To solve this issue, in the exporting step of [step-by-step tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#exporting-a-trained-model), you must change the code from :

```
python .\exporter_main_v2.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path .\models\my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn\pipeline.config --trained_checkpoint_dir .\models\my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn\ --output_directory .\exported-models\my_model
```

to:

```
python .\export_tflite_graph_tf2.py --pipeline_config_path .\models\my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn\pipeline.config --trained_checkpoint_dir .\models\my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn\ --output_directory .\exported-models\my_model
```

Note: *the export_tflite_graph_tf2 is located in tensorflow\models\research\object_detection*

After that, you may export this saved model.

You can validate the saved model input by using the below scripts in python:

```
import tensorflow as tf

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter([Your tflite Model])
print(interpreter.get_input_details())

"""expected result: [{'name': 'serving_default_input:0', 'index': 0, 'shape': array([  1, 320, 320,   3]), 'shape_signature': array([  1, 320, 320,   3]), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32), 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32), 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 'sparsity_parameters': {}}]"""
```

Comment: Kinda forgot I even asked this here. You're right, my mistake was to export a "standard" model instead of a tflite one and I had to just use the tflite exporter. Thanks for closing this in case people have the same problem!